# How to remove a dock from Plank?

Tags: uninstall, dock, plank

I wanted to move the launcher to the bottom and have it aligned in the center, so I downloaded Plank. I didn't like it so I uninstalled it but the dock still appears when I  move the cursor to the bottom of the screen.

Already tried to remove:

```
sudo apt-get remove plank
```

purged it

```
sudo apt-get purge plank
```

removed dependencies

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove plank
```

removed all files from /usr/share/app-install/desktop and /var/cache/archives/, and the dock still shows. So how do I remove it totally?

Thanks

Comment: You may need to restart / logout of the session and login again (or just quit plank), if apt-get didn't kill Plank's process during unistall. Did you install plank thought the package manager /software center in the first place ?

Comment: The correct answer is in the comment.

Answer (score 6):

**Uninstall plank**
To remove just plank package itself from Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus) execute on terminal:
`sudo apt-get remove plank`
**Uninstall plank and it's dependent packages**
To remove the plank package and any other dependant package which are no longer needed from Ubuntu Xenial.
`sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove plank`
**Purging plank**
If you also want to delete configuration and/or data files of plank from Ubuntu Xenial then this will work:

```
sudo apt-get purge plank
```

To delete configuration and/or data files of plank and it's dependencies from Ubuntu Xenial then execute:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove plank
```

Source: [Here](https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/xenial/plank?action=remove)

Answer (score 2):

Try to reset its settings in `dconf` (installable with `sudo apt-get install dconf-cli`):

```
dconf reset -f /net/launchpad/plank/
```

Try to locate Plank in the current user XDG Autostart:

```
ls .config/autostart/
# then remove plank from here
rm .config/autostart/plank*.desktop
```