# Getting rid of a second taskbar

Tags: 18.04, gnome

linux newbie here.

I recently installed ubuntu 18.04 over windows 10 yesterday, and was trying to make the taskbar somewhat like the windows one. Along the journey I somehow ended up with 2 taskbars and am confused at how I would get rid of it. I have the default one (which I want to keep), and [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0U7R.png) I am wondering what extension that gnome has would produce such a taskbar. For some extra information, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BD8PQ.png) is the gnome tweaks extension page for me.

Edit for Clarification:

I am wondering what extension produces [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0U7R.png), and how to disable it. I don't really know how to clarify this much more than I already have.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe I should embrace the difference. I don't have a lot of time to get used to the taskbar though, considering I have to get back to development relatively quickly. Then again, I probably shouldn't have made such a big change in the middle of things.

Comment: When you say over windows to me that means replacing windows. I am thinking you mean dual boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second taskbar is not a gnome extension, but an installed application. It looks very much like Plank.

To get rid of it , [run](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990086/how-to-remove-a-dock-from-plank):

```
sudo apt remove plank
```

You might need to logout + login after removing.

Comment: Thanks it worked :)